# Best SE site to ask library related questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, site-recommendation, not-constructive

Couple of days ago I asked the following question: [Language-Integrated Query (LINQ) for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15032670/1944131). IMHO the question was related to programming and it was *practical* and *answerable*; that's why I decided to post it on Stack Overflow site.

However, the question has been closed as *not constructive*. That's fine if people with much higher reputation felt it was (I trust their judgment).

Would you be able to recommend the best Stack Exchange site to ask that type of questions like this one: [Language-Integrated Query (LINQ) for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15032670/1944131)?

I am rather new user of SE websites and very honest answer to my question would help me (and I believe other new users) not to make similar *mistakes* in the future.

BTW, if you see any other issues with that question, please feel free to share it with me. I am sure all opinions will be very helpful.

**EDIT**

Thanks to your answers I have realized how many silly mistakes I have made in my question. Now I understand why I has been closed and do agree with that. Next time I need to read FAQ more carefully.

Comment: Based on the title I was ready to suggest http://libraries.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @J.Steen: Ah, I left my funny hat in the bedroom this morning. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question had two non-constructive questions within it, which is why it would have been closed. Regardless of where you posted on StackExchange (if it were on-topic elsewhere) you'd still likely get it Closed as NC.

> Do you think it is possible to have an LINQ for Java implementation / project soon?

The answer to that is either 'Yes' or 'No', neither of which are much use to anyone.

> Did you hear about any project trying to fulfill that gap between Java and C#?

Again, the answer here is either Yes/No (unconstructive) or *at best* you'll just get loads of example links to places where it has been used. Again, long lists of examples aren't of any use to anyone as there is no 'correct' example, people would just vote on which implementation they personally liked the best.

Questions on SO - and the same is true for all Stack Exchange sites - require questions that can be explicitly answered with an answer that directly solves the problem stated in the question. Unfortunately your question doesn't fall into that type of question. (Not to mention that you included two questions in there too, which would make it even harder to explicitly answer it - keep questions to one constructive question per post)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I can see my mistakes now. I need to read FAQ more carefully next time.

Comment: I think my closing paragraph could win the record for the most instances of the word 'question' in one paragraph.

Comment: @Alexandar No worries. You did exactly the right thing by coming to Meta to ask about the questions; that's what meta stackoverflow is for. Much better to ask for clarification than just just keep posting questions that get downvoted without you really understanding why.

Answer (score 4):

IMO It was closed as not constructive because of this:

> Now when Java8 is about to emerge, and will probably provide features such as Lambda Expressions, do you think it is possible to have an LINQ for Java implementation / project soon?

"about to emerge", "will probably", "do you think", these are not phrases that are practical and answerable, these are subjective and speculative

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I have realized how silly mistakes I have made.

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" is that StackExchange a Q/A site is. That means that we expect to get a question and one answer. Q/A doesn't mean *'I like ...'*, *'I think you should use the ... library'*, ect. Those are questions that needs to be asked on forums.

So, to answer your question: There is no best SE site for that question.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and help. That was very helpful. I need to follow FAQ directions next time.